# Fastest way to keep a running count of records in a Postgres table by their IDs?

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, caching, optimization

We have a query that is expecting throughput of 300-500 reqs/sec and it checks the count of rows in a table that have a specific ID.

Is there a faster way to do this other than select count(id) with an index? I'm open to unique ideas like caches, data structures, etc that do not force us to hit the DB where we can store a live count but also open to Postgres hacks.

Ideally the count should be as fresh as possible, so nothing that would result in stale data for longer than a few seconds.

Thanks!

Comment: Well... you can have a secondary table just for this purpose. Every time you insert a new ID, you increment the value in the secondary table.

Comment: The fastest way - do not do it.  Instead create a view that contains the count. Then you only get the count when you query the view, And it can **never be stale**, unless you consider uncommitted transactions as stale.

Comment: Traditionally you would use a rollup/summary table and at a larger scale maybe move to a data sketch like countmin or hyperloglog.

Comment: @Belayer isn't a view just a stored SQL statement that gets run when you select from the view? How is that going to improve the performance?

Comment: @BenManes is a rollup/summary table the same as TheImpaler's suggestion? I'm interested in the data sketch idea, how does it scale horizontally across multiple pods?

Comment: Yes a view is a stored query executed when needed and there is execution time when queried. This however should not be much if table properly indexed. On the other hand maintaining a count also has performance implications. You either run a update/process every so often (in the time frame you allow stale data) or on every DML operation, at your estimate 300-500 times/sec, which decreases performance on every DML operation.The **only** way to know is write test cases for both and test under as many conditions you can think of, including multiple DML transactions hitting currently.